# Why doent SQLite save inserted data?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I always have to keep the SQL Insert statement in my python code in order to read the data from the database. Doesn't keeping the SQL insert statement in the python code amount to inserting same data multiple times into the database? I think the data insertion statement  should be run once to insert data once, after which the data should be readable from the database. Whenever I omit the data insertion statement from my code, I am not able to read the data from the database, as though the script has not been run before.

Can someone please help me understand why this happens?

Below is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
print "Opened database successfully"
    
conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) \      VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 )")
    
conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) \      VALUES (2, 'Allen', 25, 'Texas', 15000.00 )")
```

Comment: first `import sqlite3`

Comment: then `con= sqlite3.connect('test.db')`

Comment: This seems a reasonable and reproducible question (albeit with slightly use-case-specific wording) with a positive, practical answer [+1]

Answer (score 2):

First point: you should use a `cursor` instead of calling `connection.execute` which is not part of the [db-api2 standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#connection-methods).

So you want:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(<your ssql statement here>)
```

Second point: nothing is really written to your db until you commit your transaction, so after your inserts you need :

conn.commit()

Note that [all this is very clearly explained in the FineManual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) with a complete example, so please have mercy and *read the doc* before anything else.

Third point: your "test.db" file will be looked up (and eventually created if it does not exist) in whatever the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is, so use an absolute path, always - because you cannot rely on where / how your script is called to be sure you're using the expected database.

Comment: I didn't appreciate this answer in 2017 obviously because I was a newbie then but this actually answers my question. the key point being that for data to be written into a db, the connection has be committed. Thanks Bruno